# Move Web Part from one category to another

Tags: web-part, custom, categories

Pretty simple question but cannot find an answer. I have a custom web part in the category 'Custom' I need to move it to another category.

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks.

Comment: See here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581095/change-the-category-for-web-part-to-be-displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if category means group, just edit web part properties and change the group

[image: example]